# I accidentally stashed changes and reverting my Xcode project to an old version. How do I revert this back to the changes I stashed?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, github

Using Xcode, when attempting to Push a code update to Github, I was prompted with "Pull and Stash". I accidentally selected okay and now my Xcode project is an old version (the last one pushed to GitHub). How can I revert this back to the stashed version?

Comment: @sekoyaz The Q is about [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), not stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

`git stash apply`

Additional characters to be able to post the answer

Answer (score 12):

@Super Hrush's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64173840/14351818) should work, but if you want to do it completely inside Xcode, try this:

#### 1. Go to the Source Control navigator

[image: vault icon]

#### 2. Control-click your stash, then click "Apply Stashed Changes..."

[image: drop down of stashed changes folder]

#### 3. Click "Apply Stash"

Leave "Keep stash after applying" checked so that you can come back to your changes later.
[image: confirm apply stash]

Comment: this was the answer I was expecting